# Why does creating my own custom error pages (400) leads to a Server Error with valid urls?

Tags: python, django

Hello There, I am trying to create a custom error page (404) in Django. It works well with invalid urls but with valid urls, it gives an error as:

```
Server Error (500)
```

views.py file:

```
    def error_404_view(request, exception):
        return render(request, "400.html")
```

urls.py file, Also this is my Project's urls.py not the app's:

```
    handler404 = "members.views.handler404"
```

settings.py file:

```
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you running on production? If not set `DEBUG = True`. I assume you wanted to test how your custom 404 page looked and turned it to `False`? Django does not serve static / media files in production and likely that is why you are getting the 500 error.

Comment: Did you run the collectstatic admin command before, if debug is false it may not be able to find those files